# How do I put kafka data to elasticsearch with nifi?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I want to know how to put kafka consumer data into elasticsearch in nifi.

My nifi flow : ConsumeKafka -> PutElasticsearchhttp

In the nifi flow, the PutElasticsearchhttp processor read the data, but the index was not found in the actual elasticsearch (using http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v)

I would like to ask what is not possible or what should be added.

I have checked that the TailFile processor send data to PutElasticsearchhttp processor. and index in elasticsearch is created successfully

Below there are configuration and kafka producer code.

port number :: kafka: 9092 / nifi: 8080 / elasticsearch http: 9200 / zookeeper: 2181.
version :: 2.11-1.1.0 / nifi: 1.9.2 / elasticsearch: 7.2.0 / zookeeper: 3.4.14

The broker is a personal computer and all addresses are localhost.

The configuration of the processor PutElasticsearchhttp. 
properties :: 
  Elasticsearch URL : http://localhost:9200 /
  Index             : test1 /
  Type              : json /
  The rest is the default. 
Automatically Terminate Relationships checked for failure, retry, success.

The configuration of the processor ConsumeKafka.
properties :: 
  Kafka Brokers     : localhost:9092 /
  Security Protocol : PLAINTEXT /
  Topic Name(s)     : testTopic /
  Group ID          : testGroup /
  The rest is the default
Automatically Terminate Relationships checked for success.

The kafka consumer code that sends the test string.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String v = "{" + "test"+i + "}";
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("testTopic", v));
        }
```

Comment: verify that messages are present in the topic . are you able to get the messages from consumekafka to nifi queue (queue that is present between both processors)??

Comment: try with Offset reset to "earliest" and check you are getting the messages/flowfile

Comment: thanks for comment. I solved this problem by differently formatting the message.